# Haskell : Why is this incorrect? I put a datatype as a type constructor in another data declaration

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

## Problem:

Make all combinations of 3-tuple representing noun-verb-noun sentences. To do this I decided to try and make the problem easier to read, because verbComb's future wasn't looking "clean", by playing with data types and encountered this problem. Please help!

## My Code:

```
type Letter = Char

data Word = Noun (Letter, Letter, Letter)| Verb (Letter, Letter,    Letter)
  deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

data Sentence = (Word, Word, Word)
  deriving (Show)

stops = "pbtdkg"
vowels = "aeiou"

vowelComb :: String -> String -> [(Char, Char, Char)]
vowelComb s v  = combine s v s ++ combine (reverse s) v s ++ combine s v (reverse s)
  where combine f s t = [ (x,y,z) | x <- f, y <- s, z <- t, x == 'p']

verbComb :: Word -> Word -> Sentence
verbComb = undefined
```

## Error:

`chp10.hs:88:21:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘Word’
    It could refer to either ‘Chp10.Word’, defined at chp10.hs:75:1
                          or ‘Prelude.Word’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at chp10.hs:28:8-12
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Types’)
Failed, modules loaded: none.`

Comment: Another error you will get after fixing the current one is that `data Sentence = (Word, Word, Word)` is invalid. You need to provide a data constructor, such as `data Sentence = Sentence (Word, Word, Word)`, or use a type alias as you did for `type Letter = Char`.

Comment: @amalloy Wait, are you the amalloy from DCSS?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Indeed. DCSS developer and YouTuber extraordinaire. Why?

Comment: @amalloy I'm a fan. :)

Comment: @amalloy and Rein - finally I got the rune of Zot - you started it! (took me a while)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error indicates, your type called `Word` clashes with a type called `Word` that is already in scope, part of the `Prelude` module which is implicitly included. To use your type, you either need to fully qualify it as `Chp10.Word` or hide the other conflicting type:

```
import Prelude hiding (Word)
```